# restoring a site collection database

Tags: 2010, restore

In my attempt to restore a production site collection to dev I forgot 1 step and now it's hanging.

1. I went to DB server on the DEV and deleted the DB without going to Central admin and delete the site collection.
2. I restored the dbs from production and ran the following script but keep getting error.
   stsadm -o addcontentdb -url http://portal.company.com/sales -databasename SP2010_Sales_Content -databaseserver CompanyDBServer
   I am getting "A SharePoint database named SP2010_Land_Content already exists.  You must supply another name for the new database."
3. So I go to dev CA and click on view all site collection. I see Sales and click on it but URL 
   Title Description
   Primary administrator: E-mail address: 
   Database Name 
   these are all blank.
4. Can't even delete the sc using remove-spsite

please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same issue recently and resolved it by deleting the old contentdb via stsadm (even though it was already deleted) then addcontentdb

Comment: your solution worked. but my site collection is not coming up. I have migrated other sites to dev about 3months ago and never received following error. 

Server Error in '/' Application.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /Sales/default.aspx

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5448; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5456